# ASP.NET MVC not finding Display Template partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The default display template for a model I'm using is not being used.

This code is in my main action view:

```
@if (Model.EmbeddedMediaModels != null)
{
    foreach (var mediaItem in Model.EmbeddedMediaModels)
    {
        BitmapFigureModel bitmap = mediaItem as BitmapFigureModel;
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            var mm = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(p => bitmap, this.ViewData);

            var modelTypeName = mm.ModelType.Name; // = "BitmapFigureModel"

            // Neither resolve the template.

            // Html.DisplayFor(m => bitmap);
            Html.DisplayFor(m => bitmap, modelTypeName);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Model.EmbeddedMediaModels` property is a collection of `EmbeddedMediaModel` base types, at present it just contains one object, a `BitmapFigureModel` which derives from `EmbeddedMediaModel`.

It's tempting to think that this is confusing matters, but the `ModelMetadata` instance retrieved is quite able to see the correct `BitmapFigureModel` model type.

Besides, even if I specify the model type name in the call to `DisplayFor` it still doesn't work.

And here's proof that a correctly-named display template partial view is in place.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of interest have you tried testing the `DisplayFor` with a test instance of `BitmapFigureModel` (e.g. Html.DisplayFor(m => new BitmapFigureModel {/*fill in properties*/})) to see if it's a problem with this specific case or a more general problem with resolving the Display Template?

Comment: @DaveParsons Dude, this is a good call because its led to this error which tells me I cannot do what I'm trying to (contrary to MVC team-member blog that says I can). I get "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: @DaveParsons If you want to post a proper answer, I'll thumb it up and then add my own answer with the error.

Comment: I didn't know the answer just helped debug; I wouldn't be putting anything particularly useful into an answer. Just glad it helped you find the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the advice from Brad Wilson (ASP.NET team):

> The expression-based versions are primarily used for pulling values
>   from the model (they are parametrized by the current model, as shown
>   in the example above). They can also be used for pulling values from
>   some source other than the model or ViewData (for example, with an
>   expression like “model => someOtherValue” which ignores the model
>   entirely). This makes them useful in loops.

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

It actually seems that its not possible to "ignore the model entirely". In the comments under my question DaveParsons suggests to experiment by just newing-up a model instance and passing it into `DisplayFor`, this leads to the error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

So it appears that I should stop being a smarty-pants and just use `Html.Partial` as Ehsan Sajjad suggests.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as answered. Good explanation

Comment: Thanks, I will do. SO forces a 2 day period before I can mark it, presumably to allow others to jump in with better answers and for the voting to take place.

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => mediaItem.Name)
```

if you want to load the partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/BitmapFigureModel.cshtml", mediaItem)
```

or:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/BitmapFigureModel.cshtml", mediaItem)
```

In your **BitmapFigureModel.cshtml**:

```
@model BitmapFigureModel
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `Html.DisplayFor(m => mediaItem)`? `bitmap ` is just the casted `mediaItem`...

Comment: If I don't cast the `mediaItem` then the MediaMetadata sees it as the wrong model type.

Comment: Obviously, your first line of code is semantically completely different to my intentions. Are you implying that I cannot use `DisplayFor` for displaying any arbitrary object, i.e. that it must be a property on the current model?

Comment: you are trying to display label for the property or you are trying to load partia view with the inner model

Comment: I'm just trying to display the complex object model using its default template.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 anyway for the fact that I should be just using good old `RenderPartial`

Comment: isn't this will work by passing that item and set model in that partial view, this not solves your problem?